# Synchronized MultiThreaded Java application ends in Livelock or Deadlock in 1 of every 100 or so runs

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently working an a sample of the Producer/Consumer problem which uses a bank account as an example. The rules are simple; You must move 3 types of currency's through a bank account and once one currency is deposited, another type cannot be until the balance is 0 again.

I have implemented what I thought was a sound logical solution, but i notices after running the program a few hundred times, every now and then( 1/100ish runs) the program deadlocks or livelocks. I am not sure how to find out the difference. But I cannot seem to uncover the root of this.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain why this is happening, as, as far as i can tell the logic appears sound to me, but obviously I am missing something.

Code Follows

```
package com.lab9;

public class Account
{
    Currency balance;

//    private static boolean deposited = false;

    Account(double amt, String currency)
    {
        this.balance = new Currency(amt, currency);
    }
    public synchronized void deposit(Currency depositAmt)
    {
       // System.out.println("Starting Deposit");
        while (this.balance.getAmount() != 0.0)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.balance.deposit(depositAmt);
        notifyAll();

    }
    public synchronized void withdrawal(Currency withdrawal)
    {
        //System.out.println("Starting Withdrawal");

        while (this.balance.getCurrency() != withdrawal.getCurrency() )
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            this.balance.withdrawal(withdrawal.getAmount());
            this.balance.setCurrency();
            notifyAll();

    }
}
```

```
package com.lab9;

public class Currency
{
    private double amount;
    private String currency;

    Currency(double amount, String currency)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void deposit(Currency deposit)
    {
        this.amount += deposit.getAmount();
        this.currency = deposit.getCurrency();
        System.out.println("Deposit Successful of amount: " + deposit.getAmount() );
    }
    public void withdrawal(double amt)
    {
        if(this.amount >= amt)
        {
            amount -=amt;
            System.out.println("Withdrawal Successful Amount of:" + amt);
        }
    }
    public void setCurrency()
    {
        this.currency = "";
    }

}
```

```
package com.lab9;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        Account strangeAccount = new Account(0.0, "");
        Currency[] transfers = {
                new Currency(1.0,"Dollars"),
                new Currency(2.0,"Euros"),
                new Currency(3.0,"Pounds")
        };
        for(var t : transfers)
        {
            new Thread(() -> strangeAccount.deposit(t)).start();
        }
        for(var t : transfers)
        {
            new Thread(() -> strangeAccount.withdrawal(t)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the program locks?

Comment: It stops executing and just sits after a deposit

Comment: That means its either livelocked or deadlocked doesn't it? I am still just learning about multi threading

Comment: Use a debugger. Looks to me like you could get stuck in an infinite loop in both of your `while` loops

Comment: Yeah I used one and I was figuring the same thing, but I dont understand why its happening. especially at such a small occurrence rate. Like is there something wrong with the way I synchronized the functions?